# SQL - разбить данные на два столбца

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть таблица типа patient_id, fio, sex(пол), date(дата регистрации). Необходимо сделать свод, сколько женщин зарегистрировалось в одном месяце, сколько в другом. То есть на выходе должна получится таблица вида:

| Пол | Май | Апрель |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Жен | 5 | 6 |
| Муж | 2 | 15 |

```
select case when tag_period='per1' then count(c_pat_all) end as c_pat_all_1,
       case when tag_period='per2' then count(c_pat_all) end as c_pat_all_2
from(
select * from(
select ls.pat_id as c_pat_all
, 'per1' as tag_period from list_serv ls
where ls.dat between TO_DATE('2023-03-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and TO_DATE('2023-03-31 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
)
union all
select * from(
select ls.pat_id as c_pat_all
, 'per2' as tag_period from list_serv ls
where ls.dat between TO_DATE('2023-04-01 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and TO_DATE('2023-04-30 00:00:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
)
)
group by tag_period
```

подскажите, какими средствами  sql oracle это можно сделать? Проблема возникает при попытке вывода двух столбцов.
На выходе получаю пустые строки вида:
[image: Результат]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задавать хорошие вопросы про sql?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/169/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте PIVOT

```
SELECT
  "Пол",
  COALESCE("Май", 0) AS "Май",
  COALESCE("Апрель", 0) AS "Апрель"
FROM
  (SELECT
    sex AS "Пол",
    TO_CHAR(date, 'Month') AS "Месяц",
    COUNT(*) AS "Количество"
  FROM
    your_table
  GROUP BY
    sex, TO_CHAR(date, 'Month')
  )
PIVOT
(
  SUM("Количество")
  FOR "Месяц" IN ('Май', 'Апрель')
)
ORDER BY
  CASE "Пол" WHEN 'Жен' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;
```